# Scala -- multiple F-bounded types in inheritance tree

Tags: scala, polymorphism, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have a generic F-bounded trait in Scala. Lets me write methods that return the same underlying implementation type, super! But now lets say a sub-trait *also* defines methods that require F-bounding. Scala is sending me back compile errors that don't make sense:

```
package sandbox

import sandbox.ComplexImpl.AnyComplexImpl

import scala.language.existentials

trait FBounded[IMPL <: FBounded[IMPL]] { self: IMPL =>
  def foo: IMPL
}

trait FBoundedUser[F <: FBounded[F]] {
  def bar(value: F): F = value.foo
}

trait SimpleImpl extends FBounded[SimpleImpl] {
  override def foo: SimpleImpl = this
}

object SimpleUser extends FBoundedUser[SimpleImpl]

// A-OK so far...

trait ComplexImpl[IMPL <: ComplexImpl[IMPL]] extends FBounded[IMPL] { self: IMPL =>
  def baz: IMPL
}

object ComplexImpl {
  type AnyComplexImpl = ComplexImpl[T] forSome { type T <: ComplexImpl[T] }
}

object ComplexUser1 extends FBoundedUser[ComplexImpl[_]]
object ComplexUser2 extends FBoundedUser[AnyComplexImpl]
```

Trying to compile with either of `ComplexUser1` or `ComplexUser2` results in:

```
Error:(32, 29) type arguments [sandbox.ComplexImpl.AnyComplexImpl] do not conform to trait
               FBoundedUser's type parameter bounds [F <: sandbox.FBounded[F]]
```

Which doesn't make sense to me. `AnyComplexImpl` definitely implements `FBounded`. Am I missing something, or is the type checker just failing me here?

EDIT:

```
class Concrete() extends ComplexImpl[Concrete] {
  override def baz: Concrete = this

  override def foo: Concrete = this
}
object ComplexUser3 extends FBoundedUser[Concrete]
```

Compiles just fine. So why won't the generic version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint requires `AnyComplexImpl` to implement `FBounded[AnyComplexImpl]`, which it doesn't, not just `FBounded[T] forSome { type T <: ComplexImpl[T] }`.

It works if you make `FBounded` and `ComplexImpl` covariant. The compiler reasons that:

1. `AnyComplexImpl` is a supertype of any `ComplexImpl[T]`, where `T <: ComplexImpl[T]`;
2. So `FBounded[T] forSome { type T <: ComplexImpl[T] }` is a subtype of `FBounded[AnyComplexImpl]`;
3. So `AnyComplexImpl` is a subtype of `FBounded[AnyComplexImpl]`.

But I suspect trying to mix F-bounded types and existentials is likely to lead to other problems down the line. The reason `ComplexUser1` and `ComplexUser2` don't compile is precisely that they are not generic. Consider using actually generic version instead:

```
def complexUser4[T <: ComplexImpl[T]] = new FBoundedUser[T] {}
```

Comment: Aha! Co/contravariance is one corner of the type system I'm still trying to get a better grasp on. Thanks.